# Huge Android project. fragments vs activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm making huge android client application (a lot of modules and views) you can compare it to facebook app.
In small projects I was using 1-2 activities and many fullscreen fragments.
But in this project it's fundametal to decide when use activity and when fragments.

Atm i have 2 activities
-LoginActivity(Launcher)
-MainActivity- it contains toolbar and one main layout where I replace all fragments.

Am I doing right ?

Comment: i would say: f**k the fragments (especially when you are using them for app navigation: i mean fragment replacing another fragment replacing yet another fragment), sooner or later you will have to pull out hairs of your head, use activities instead

Comment: Can't say that I don't agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on your logic. However, you can devide your view into categories (each category is an activity) while fragment can be as sub category... :)